# How to set maximum height for activity (Dialog themed)

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm optimising our Android application for tablets. For much of the application, we're using fragments but for some settings screens, we just want to launch the screen as a dialog for tablets. To achieve this, we set the theme of the Activity in the Manifest

```
<activity
    android:name="com.company.app.EditTaxTypeSettingsActivity"
    android:theme="@style/ActivityTheme">
</activity>
```

And here's the theme (in res/values-large-v11):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>         
    <style name="ActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">      
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The activities using this theme open as a dialog and look fine in landscape orientation. But in portrait mode, the dialogs fill the screen vertically which looks silly.

How can I set the maximum height of these dialogs? I have tried settings the maxHeight attribute of the theme `<item name="android:maxHeight">500dip</item>` but it seems to refer to the dialog container around the activity content rather than to activity content itself. (ie, if I set the height of the Activity theme to 500dip, the dialog just gets a very large dialog title area)

I also tried setting the size of the activities layout xml (RelativeLayout) but I can't set a maxHeight, I can only set the height but I can't hard code the height there because I have Save and Cancel buttons set to `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` so they can remain above the keyboard when the keyboard pops up. (Hard coding the activities layout height, prevents the save/cancel buttons from remaining on top of the keyboard)

Thanks, does anyone know how to set a maximum dialog height, preferably at the theme level?

Comment: I'm confused why you would use a `Fragment` by itself as a `Dialog`. Just use `DialogFragment`. It'll correctly size the info you need just to fit what you are trying to show.

Comment: @Andy - They are activities that were designed for phones. We don't want to start a whole new activity (taking up a whole tablet screen with only a small amount of information). Since they work better as dialogs rather than fragments, we have decided not to convert the phone activities to fragments, rather we want the activities to open as dialogs. So they are activities, not fragments. Thanks.

Comment: Oh Ok I get you. So what you are saying is you will still have Activities, but you want the phone designed activities to be Dialogs for Tablets?

Comment: @Andy Yes. And it's working like that but I am just hoping I can somehow set the maximum height of those dialogs so they don't look silly in portrait mode taking up the entire height of the screen.

Comment: Well I believe what I told you might actually work in your case. It encapsulates the Activity in question, but into a dialog, making it more of what it should be, a Dialog, even if its on a tablet. And to be honest, just change it from an `Activity` to a `Fragment` or `DialogFragment`. There is very little code to change. Actually there is something called `FragmentActivity` as well. Check that stuff out so you know what I mean. It'll make more sense. Also feel free to go on my Github to see an example of a `DialogFragment`. But in either case, if not, just thought I'd provide alternatives

Comment: As for setting a maximum height in a `Dialog`, I am looking at the Doc, and there is no attribute to do this. So to answer your question, there is not a way to set the maximum height. You would need to use `Fragments`

Comment: @Andy Thanks, I'll have a go at DialogFragment or FragmentActivity and see if I can make it work without too much code changing.

Answer (score 2):

Use this method to fix the height of the `Window` for your activity with Dialog theme.

```
public static void maxinumDialogWindowHeight(Window window) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layout = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    layout.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
    layout.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
    window.setAttributes(layout);
}
```

And use it after `setContentView()` (it will reset the Window layout to `wrap_content`):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.messages);
    if (getWindow().isFloating()) ViewHelper.maxinumDialogWindowHeight(getWindow());

    // rest of your code...
}
```